# finding largest entry in 2d array with threaded function

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

I'm struggling to write a threaded program in c++ that is accurate and faster than my non-threaded version.

I'm finding the largest entry in a 2d array of random doubles.

Here is the general code:

```
void getLargest(double** anArray, double largestEntry, int dimLower, int dimUpper, int dim) {

    for (int i = dimLower; i < dimUpper; i++) {
        for (int  j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            if (anArray[i][j] > largestEntry) {
                largestEntry = anArray[i][j]; 
            }
        }
    }

}
int main(){

  // Seed the random number generator
  srand( time(NULL));

  // 2D array dimension
  int dim = 30000;

  // Specify max values
  double max = (double) (dim * dim * dim);
  double min = (double) (dim * dim * dim * -1.0);

  double t1 = get_wallTime();
  // Create a 2D array
  double **myArray = new double*[dim];
  for (int i=0; i<dim; i++){
    myArray[i] = new double[dim];
    for (int j=0; j<dim; j++){
      // generate random number
      myArray[i][j] = genRandNum(min, max);
    }
  }

  double largestEntry = 0.0;
  int portion = dim / 5;
  std::future<void> thread1 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, 0, portion, dim);
  thread1.get();

  std::future<void> thread2 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, portion, (portion * 2), dim);
  thread2.get();

  std::future<void> thread3 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, (portion * 2), (portion * 3), dim);
  thread3.get();

  std::future<void> thread4 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, (portion * 3), (portion * 4), dim);
  thread4.get();

  std::future<void> thread5 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, (portion *4), dim, dim);
  thread5.get();

  double t2 = get_wallTime();
  double t3 = t2 - t1;

  cout << " The largest entry is " << largestEntry << endl;  

  cout << "runtime : " <<  t3 << "\n";
}
```

I have the appropriate #includes.
I understand my code as updating the double `largestEntry` from each thread if the portion of the 2d array that the thread is processing has a larger entry than the thread prior to it. Then I output the largest entry, and the runtime.

Here is the output:

```
 The largest entry is 0
runtime : 14.7113
```

This runs way faster than I'm expecting it to, and the largest entry should not be zero. Basically, I'm having trouble finding why that is. I'm not very comfortable with using `async`, but when I have before, this method worked very well. I know I'm not updating `largestEntry` correctly, though I'm unsure of where I've made a mistake.

Thanks for any advice you guys could give.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `largestEntry` into `getLargest` by value, so when it is updated only the value within the function is updated, not the value in `main`.

Two other notes:  The `thread1.get()` etc. calls should all be after the threads are created, so they all run simultaneously.

Two, each thread should return it's own value for `largestEntry` (it can be the value of the future), then compare those to find the largest.  If they all reference the same variable you're going to get into race conditions between the threads, CPU cache thrashing, and possibly bad answers depending on how the optimizer handles the updates to largestEntry (it could avoid writing the value out until all the looping was done).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What would be the solution to passing `largestEntry` by reference, instead of value? I've tried a few things but I'm unsure how it works in c++.

Comment: @slippeel You can pass it in by reference or pointer, but each thread will need to work with it's own copy of `largestEntry`.  Returning it as the result of `getLargest` (which will become the value of the future) would be better than passing it is as a parameter.