# threading in c++, finding largest entry in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

I'm having some trouble finding the largest entry in a 2d array with a threaded function. I've been glued to the screen for hours now, and I could use some help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// A vanilla random number generator
double genRandNum(double min, double max){

  return min + (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (max - min)));

}

double get_wallTime() {
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return (double) (tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec/1000000.0);
} 

void getLargest(double** anArray, double largestEntry, int dimLower, int dimUpper, int dim) {

    for (int i = dimLower; i < dimUpper; i++) {
        for (int  j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            if (anArray[i][j] > largestEntry) {
                largestEntry = anArray[i][j]; 
            }
        }
    }

}

// Main routine
int main(){

  // Seed the random number generator
  srand( time(NULL));

  // 2D array dimension
  int dim = 30000;

  // Specify max values
  double max = (double) (dim * dim * dim);
  double min = (double) (dim * dim * dim * -1.0);

  double t1 = get_wallTime();
  // Create a 2D array
  double **myArray = new double*[dim];
  for (int i=0; i<dim; i++){
    myArray[i] = new double[dim];
    for (int j=0; j<dim; j++){
      // generate random number
      myArray[i][j] = genRandNum(min, max);
    }
  }

  double largestEntry = 0.0;
  double largestEntry2 = 0.0;
  double largestEntry3 = 0.0;
  double largestEntry4 = 0.0;
  double largestEntry5 = 0.0;
  int portion = dim / 5;
  std::future<void> thread1 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry, 0, portion, dim);

  std::future<void> thread2 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry2, portion, (portion * 2), dim);

  std::future<void> thread3 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry3, (portion * 2), (portion * 3), dim);

  std::future<void> thread4 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry4, (portion * 3), (portion * 4), dim);

  std::future<void> thread5 = std::async (std::launch::async, getLargest, myArray, largestEntry5, (portion *4), dim, dim);
  thread1.get();
  thread2.get();
  thread3.get();
  thread4.get();

  thread5.get();


  if (largestEntry2 > largestEntry) {
     largestEntry = largestEntry2;
  } 
  if (largestEntry3 > largestEntry) {
    largestEntry = largestEntry3;
  }
  if (largestEntry4 > largestEntry) {
    largestEntry = largestEntry4;
  }
  if (largestEntry5 > largestEntry) {
    largestEntry = largestEntry5;
  }

  double t2 = get_wallTime();
  double t3 = t2 - t1;

  cout << " The largest entry is " << largestEntry << endl;  

  cout << "runtime : " <<  t3 << "\n";
}
```

I believe I'm setting everything up correctly, but I've just learned how to use async so I'm sure something is incorrect. When run, I get zero as the output of the largest entry, which is wrong, and I get a runtime much longer than I'm expecting.

Here is the output:

```
 The largest entry is 0
runtime : 13.8261
```

I think I'm passing in `largestEntry` to the threaded function incorrectly, but I have no idea how to fix it. The threaded function, `getLargest`, is supposed to find the largest entry of the array it's provided, and when I create the threads I assign each of them a portion of the array.

Any advice anyone could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a followup to [finding largest entry in 2d array with threaded function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535657/finding-largest-entry-in-2d-array-with-threaded-function) and OP did not fix all the problems mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are just changing the value of the local `largestEntry` parameter. This will not change anything in the calling program.

One solution is to pass in `largestEntry` as a reference (change your function to say `double &largestEntry` in its parameter list)

Note that this has nothing to do with threading, you could just call your function normally to test it.

Edit: I had trouble with using a reference when I tried it (could just be a old compiler) - if references don't work, you could always pass the `largestEntry` as a pointer - `double *largestEntry` in the function parameter list and a few `*` and `&`  placed in the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Passing by reference did not work for me, with threading, where else in the code would I place `*` and `&` to pass by pointer?

Comment: If you change the parameter to be a pointer then you will need to dereference the pointer inside the function by using `*largestEntry` (in two places). You will also need to pass the address of the variable to the function when you call it. Do this by using an `&`, eg. `&largestEntry3` in your main() function.

Comment: I changed it based on your first comment, to make `getLargest` return a value instead of update one, and I received favorable results. However, not as much of a speedup as I would have hoped.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been described in the last answer by The Dark. However, i find the solution not ideal. For me, it would be more logical that your function returned the value thus found rather than write it in a parameter.

That way you can use the get() function of the `future` to obtain the answer when the threads are finished, and you do not use references or pointers where it is really not needed.

Note: simply using a reference would not work here because the parameter to `std::async` are copied, the same way as for `std::thread`. If you want it to work with a reference, you need to use `std::ref` ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)) in that case.

Comment: Yes, returning the value makes more sense, rather than as a parameter.